# Linking github page to a google domain

Tags: github, dns

I've perused SO for a bit, but i must be doing something wrong because i still can't get it to work.
I'm trying to link a domain name i got on Google to the index.html in my github repository.
I followed the steps here https://dev.to/trentyang/how-to-setup-google-domain-for-github-pages-1p58

but still keep getting an error:
[image]

when running the script, the response i get is

[image]

i'm not sure what this ghs.googlehosted.com is, when it's supposed to be solarmew.github.io. and why there's an extra third one too.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The authoritative documentation is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site). It's impossible to tell what's wrong with your setup without seeing the contents of the CNAME file and the DNS settings in the Google Domains dashboard.

Comment: You have a redundant CNAME file in the `docs` directory, though the publishing source is the root directory. I can see that for your last successful pages build, you had the publishing source still set to `docs`. The site is actually reachable under your custom domain, and the theme CSS is also there at https://www.samearlwood.com/assets/css/style.css; try triggering another build by committing and pushing a change, and keeping the current config settings; that should make your `index.html` visible at the right place.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks for the reply. Could you please dumb it down a bit more for me. I'm not sure what the main / (root) and main / docs directories are or how to get to them. It now says "DNS check successful" but going to the page still gives 404 error.
Edit: Oh, i see them now when using the desktop github. But still not super sure how to fix it.

Comment: I got rid of CNAME in docs and left the one in root. Still doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: IT WORKS!!!
Thanks :)